# How to create a list with inputs in python 3.4?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input

I am working on this piece of code;

```
def dataEntry():
    x = True;
    while x == True:
        entData = input()
        Lst = entData
        if entData == "stop":
            return Lst
```

I am trying to get inputs int and float one on each line until the user types stop. After getting the inputs i want to create a list formed by those inputs to work on later. I tried many things but end up getting just "stop" as it is the last input. I realise that the problem is i have to create a list before getting inputs and add every input into it every single time but couldnt find a solution.

Comment: You couldn't figure out how to add something to a list? You didn't look very hard.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try using:

```
Lst =[]
if entData != "stop":
    Lst.append(entData)
```

This function will push the new input into the list.

Comment: So, just add that line in after `Lst = entData`? I don't think that's going to work, since `Lst` is a string and strings don't have an `append` method.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was list, fixed my answer now. Yeah, you should use a `list` instead of a string.

Comment: So, just add `Lst =[]` after `while x == True:`? I don't think that will work because it will make a new `Lst` in every loop instead of accumulating values.

Comment: Add it above the loop

Comment: Oh, ok :-) that ought to work.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Much appreciated

Comment: Happy to help. Do mark it as accepted so that it will help other fellow developers with same problems

Comment: Faced another problem now :/. My input has to be int or float, when i use `float(input())` the loop doesn't work because stop is a string. I tried to slice the list afterwards and get rid of "stop" but this didn't work `Lst[:-4]` the output list still has "stop" in it. Sorry if I am asking a lot but I am only a student trying to do an assignment.

Comment: use `Lst.append(float(entData))`

Comment: I get this error. ValueError: could not convert string to float 'stop'.

Comment: You should use the if condition first, if the string is not float, then convert it into float.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to open a chat if you are willing and have the time can you do try and open a chat. I couldnt understand the last part you said

Comment: `if entData != "stop"` then append to list `else: return Lst`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. I won't bother you anymore :D. Thanks for the help  again

Comment: No problem. Happy to help